# Prove there exists $f \in C^{\infty}$, bounded derivatives,

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, analyticity

I know the title isn't very comprehensible, but I don't know how to improve it.

Here is a problem which I don't know how to solve.

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}, \ \ \alpha \in \mathbb{R}, \ \ \varepsilon > 0$. Prove that there exists $f$ class $C ^{\infty}$ such that

$|f^{(k)}(x)|\le \varepsilon$ for $k = 0,1,...,n-1$,  $ \ \ x \in \mathbb{R}$,

$f^{(k)}(0)=0$ for $k=0,1,...,n-1$

$f^{(n)}(0)=\alpha$.

Could you help me with that?

Comment: something seems to be missing: do you mean to say $f^{(k)}(0) = 0$ and I assume you mean $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Yes, I meant $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I also changed $f^{(k)} = 0$ into $f^{(k)}(0) = 0$. The problem is originally as stated before (with n natural), but if you think it makes more sense now, please help :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$f(x) = c(\varepsilon,n,\alpha,\beta) x^n e^{-\beta x^2}$$ Choose $c(\varepsilon,n,\alpha,\beta)$ to ensure $|f^{(k)}(x)|\le \varepsilon$  and $f^{(n)}(0)=\alpha$.